# Problem exporting SQL Server management Studio Express to Go Daddy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, ssms

I'm having a terrible time exporting SQL Server Management Studio Express tables to the Go Daddy webserver.  Go Daddy support can't help either.  I started by using Microsoft Database Publishing Wizard for SQL Server thinking it would be 'easy'....not!  I ran into user/password errors even though I was using the user and password that was created for the SQL database in the Go Daddy site.  I called help desk support at Go Daddy and went through several iterations of processes to get the thing working but it didn't.  Finally, the support guy acted like his phone went on the blip and scuttled away.

There has got to be someway to upload SQL Server to a webserver without a lot of drama.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method to move a SQL Server Database between two servers is to use the Backup and Restore method.

1. Take a FULL database [backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) of your
   source database.
2. [Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) the database backup to your
   new server.

You may find the following Microsoft SQL Server Forum thread useful:

[How do you backup a database using sql server 2005 express?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/95750bdf-fcb1-45bf-9247-d7c0e1b9c8d2)

Consult the SQL Server Documentation for performing a database backup and restore using T-SQL.

Here is the [GoDaddy documentation](http://help.godaddy.com/article/3379) for performing a SQL Server Database restore.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Turns out there are two paths/usernames/passwords that you have to use in the database publishing wizard.  This first one is to access Go Daddy and the 2nd is the access the database. I didn't realize there was a different sever address when I entered the database information.  As soon as that was fixed I was able to use the database publishing wizard.

I tried the backup and restore, but you can't restore to the Go Daddy database if the back up was created outside of Go Daddy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can use the query analyzer in the Go Daddy database to upload the SQL script to create the tables.  That worked.  However, all of the relationships did not transfer.  It looks like all of the fields transferred upon first glance.  I guess, I'll have to manage the relationships directly on the site.  Not sure why they didn't transfer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have problem with uploading SQL server database to GoDaddy please look at http://jahan1987.blogspot.com/2012/08/godaddy-sql-server-2008-database-upload.html